# Flash p2p: managing clients

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, p2p, flash-media-server, adobe-cirrus

What's the best way of managing clients in p2p (cirrus) application? For example, I want to make a game for 2 players. User clicks button "Play", and another random user (who also clicked "play"), will become his opponent. And I'm trying to understand, what's the best way of managing such online users, who clicked "play". And how can I understand, that someone went offline? What server technology will be the best one? I'm thinking of FMS, but if I have it, I do not need p2p, do I? I could just use *client1 <--> FMS <--> client2* scheme to make the game.
Thanks for help.

Comment: The game will have a lot more latency if you use a client1 <--> FMS <--> client2 rather than a client1 <--> client2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at https://github.com/s9tpepper/RealtimeGameLib
or
http://code.google.com/p/cocoon-p2p/

I use FMS and SharedObject.getRemote() for active users roster.

But if you are building an application available only for P2P users, you could use NetGroup and bootstrap users via Stratus/Cirrus `groupspec.serverChannelEnabled = true` (like tomkrcha does in realtimegamelib).

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/p2p_rtmfp_groups.html